# NSPredicate Exact Match For To-Many Core Data Relationship

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate

If I have a `Blog` that has many `Tag`s, how would I create an `NSPredicate` that would get all `Blog`s that have two, and only two, specific `Tag`s?

This:

```
NSPredicate *tagsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags == %@", tagsArray];
```

Leadings to a fatal error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

I thought that since Core Data uses sets for to-many relationships, I should use an `NSSet`, but that gives the same error.

I'm stumped, because other formats like `ANY tags.name IN %@` will return any of the `Blog`s that contain any of the two `Tag`s. `ALL` combined with `IN` leads to a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate ALL tags.name IN {iOS, programming}'
```

Is what I want not possible without filtering results after the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t IN %@).@count = 2 AND SUBQUERY(tags, $t, NOT $t IN %@).@count = 0", tagsArray, tagsArray];
```

(ie. in natural language, the count of tags matching my array is 2, and the count not matching my array is 0).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wasn't impossible!